# IMAP_OPEN in outlook not working using PHP

Tags: php, outlook

Hello i have this IMAP_Open for my email in outlook to fetch data on it. I am facing problems because the connection can't connect using outlook. Now in the first place, I am using gmail which is really okay and it can connect to it. now my problem in outlook is the connection always failed. Here is the error below,

```
Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in C:\xampp\htdocs\tpccr\Config.php on line 29
Cannot connect to Outlook: Too many login failures
Notice: Unknown: LOGIN failed. (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: LOGIN failed. (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: LOGIN failed. (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Too many login failures (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

This is the code that connects to my outlook imap

```
$connection = imap_open('{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', 'sample@sample.com', 'password') or die('Cannot connect to Outlook: ' . imap_last_error());
```

Now the connection for outlook mail is outlook.office365.com:993 and got no luck. Can someone help me figured this thing out? Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Your PHP imap_open string is ok for outlook mailboxes (I checked by using my MS mailbox), but according to the error message --- "Too many login failures", it probably means the mailbox is blocked due to too many PREVIOUS login failures.  It is a common practice that a mail server will block a IMAP login if there were too many failed attempts. I suggest you to (1) use the same machine, install an email client and try to login the outlook account. If it still fails, it means that the problem is due to too many failed logins. Then (2) use another IP to login and see whether it works.

Comment: hello @KenLee thanks for replying. what you mean install an email client. i am logging into my email via browser. is that okay?

Comment: no if you login thru the browser to check,  the IP they detects will be that of the server side, so of course it will not have the IMAP login failures error.

Comment: @KenLee can you help me on this one? i badly need help :-(

Comment: @KenLee so you mean the outlook needs to be login on the outlook in your laptop not into the browser

Comment: First question: did you **ever** successfully login (thru PHP IMAP_OPEN) in your xampp server ?? If the answer is negative, please check your firewall first.

Comment: @KenLee i already solve it! using my own server email but my problem is the companies email. i think the link to it is not outlook.office365.com

Comment: Great. Have a nice day.